# openxml adding a worksheet to existing workbook, becomes corrupt

Tags: file, openxml, new-operator, worksheet, corrupt

I have the below code, which when executed for the first time with the file question missing, it will be created and adds a new worksheet nicely.

if i run it the second time, and change the worksheet_name to say fred2, it will create the worksheet but the excel file will open up with a corruptions warning, but can click ok and it opens up anyway.

Can someone point out why / what i am doing wrong,

thanks

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;

String l_email_file     = "abc.xlsx";
String l_worksheet_name = "fred";

if (File.Exists(l_fileName))
{
    spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(l_fileName, true);

    // Add a blank WorksheetPart.

    /*WorksheetPart */
    worksheetPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();

}
else
{
    printinfo("1 ctreate file name", l_fileName);
    spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(l_fileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();

    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.  

    workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.  
    /*WorksheetPart */
    worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.  
    sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());
}

sheet = new Sheet()
{
    Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
    SheetId = 1,
    Name = l_worksheet_name
};
sheets.Append(sheet);
Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet();
SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();


Row row = new Row();

for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{
    row = new Row();
    for (int j = 1; j <= 6; j++)
    {
        Cell cell = new Cell()
        {
            CellReference = "?",
            DataType = CellValues.String,
            CellValue = new CellValue(i + j.ToString())
        };
        row.Append(cell);
    }
    sheetData.Append(row);
}

worksheet.Append(sheetData);
worksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet;

// Close the document.  
spreadsheetDocument.Close();
```

Comment: im sure the repeated SheetId = 1 is incorrect, but ill leave question up whilst i fix rthat

Answer (score 0):

not incrementing the sheet id, pretty stupid

```
//int sheetIndex = 0;
                foreach (WorksheetPart worksheetpart in workbook2.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts)
                {
                    //Worksheet worksheet = worksheetpart.Worksheet;
                    //
                    //foreach (SheetData l_sheetData2 in worksheet.Elements<SheetData>())
                    //{
                    //
                    //     int i=1;
                    //}
                    sheetId++;
                    printinfo("incing the sheet id", sheetId.ToString());
                }
```